# Why is the meaning of good in most dictionaries described as both acceptable/satisfactory in one sense and excellent/high quality in another sense?

Tags: semantics, connotation, language-formation

When we type **good** in most online dictionaries including Oxford, Collins, Webster etc, various meanings come out. However, when it comes to standard, quality or performance both senses are given:

1. satisfactory or acceptable
2. excellent; high quality

How can good mean both of these levels or does the context vary? The example sentences they provide do not really make it any clearer.

Comment: It depends on the context: 'good' is such a wide-ranging adjective you might need to find a more specific one. 'Good' means 'not bad' and IMO it is a 'weak' adjective... a bit like 'nice'.

Comment: 'Good' can also mean 'considerable', 'full', 'well-founded' ....

Comment: The word 'good' (with small exceptions) denotes general approval:  Good/Satisfactory/Bad.   Increasingly, however, these words have been affected by rank ordering to allow for alignment with numerical scales.  So in Ofsted schools inspection grading we have outstanding(1)/good(2)/Requires Improvement(3)/inadequate(4).  But if you have a 7-point scale and need seven words, there might be words better than satisfactory but less than good.  A former Chief Inspector for schools actually insisted that 'satisfactory' schools were not good enough.  And 'adequate' sounds inferior to satisfactory.

Comment: How can you boil down ' "good" in most online dictionaries' to two examples?

Yes 'good' can mean 'satisfactory or acceptable, excellent or of high quality…' depending on the context. In fact, good can mean anything more positive than 'neutral'.

Quite separately please be very clear, most dictionary examples are purely grammatical and show nothing about semantics, ie meaning.